# finding max value of one field associated with another constant field in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, max

I have three fields in a postsql query as shown below:

```
point     |      time a         |      time b
----------+---------------------+--------------------
     1    |2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-26 00:00:00  
     1.5  |2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-25 00:00:00  
     1.75 |2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-24 00:00:00  
     1.25 |2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-23 00:00:00
     2    |2018-09-28 00:00:00 | 2018-09-26 00:00:00  
     2.5  |2018-09-28 00:00:00 | 2018-09-25 00:00:00  
     2.7  |2018-09-28 00:00:00 | 2018-09-24 00:00:00  
     2.1  |2018-09-28 00:00:00 | 2018-09-23 00:00:00
```

Now time a has 4 constant values with different time b fields associated with it as shown above.

How can I make a query to find the maximum time b field for each different time a value?

I know that previous suggestions mentioned I should do things such as :

row_number() OVER (partition by time a order by time b).  However I am having a lot of trouble applying this when there is the extra field.

The desired output of the postgresql query would be:

```
point  |  time a             |      time b
-------+---------------------+--------------------
 1     |2018-09-27 00:00:00 | 2018-09-26 00:00:00  
 2     |2018-09-28 00:00:00 | 2018-09-26 00:00:00
```

How can I tweak the above query to get the above desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows functions for that. Something like this:

```
select time_a, time_b
from (select time_a, time_b, row_number() 
  over (partition by time_a order by time_b DESC) from times)t
where row_number = 1
```

For each group of time_a your getting the row number for every value of time_b. Since they are ordered, the number one will be the max. Finally you need an outer select to filter.

This approach is more flexible than just grouping in case you have any other field in the table that you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=92368dcdc32a8ac49c589ba624a1f83f)

You can `GROUP BY trunc(point)` which first truncates the decimal part of `point` and then groups the integer part.

```
SELECT trunc(point), max(time_a), max(time_b) 
FROM times
GROUP BY trunc(point)
```

If you are sure that `time_a` is constant per `point` as in your example it can be written as:

```
SELECT trunc(point), time_a, max(time_b) 
FROM times
GROUP BY trunc(point), time_a
```

Otherwise you can take the `point` independent version over the `time_a` column:

```
SELECT trunc(MIN(point)), time_a, max(time_b) 
FROM times
GROUP BY time_a
```